# Insatiable Vs. desirable (Word Choice)

Tags: word-choice

> The need for cheap entertainment for soldiers combined with the wartime imaginations of American youth fueled **an insatiable** market for comic books.

A. NO CHANGE

B. a discontent

C. a desirable

D. an uncontrollable

Here, I eliminated B and D because of negative tone. I don't see a reason why C is wrong. For A, I thought it could be eliminated because overall tone of the text is normal/formal, and it is little advance level word, which we don't use in daily life. However, the correct answer is A, not C.

Can anyone give me some explanation for this question?

Answer (score 1):

An "insatiable market for comic books" means that people want to buy so many comic books that it's not possible to make enough comic books to satisfy the market.

This has nothing to do with whether having comic books available for sale is desirable or undesirable, so answer "C" would dramatically change the meaning of the sentence.

If you are meant to find the answer that is closest to a synonym for the bolded word, then "D" ("uncontrollable") would be a reasonable answer.

If you're only meant to suggest a change if the existing sentence is not fluent, then "A" is the correct answer, because the existing sentence is perfectly grammatical and would be a very typical thing to read in a newspaper or news magazine.